# How do I use jQuery selectors with an object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an unordered list in an object:

```
var myUL = $('ul#theID'); //I send this var to another function in the code
```

I want the direct children only of this object (I have another 'ul' within each 'li' that also has 'li's in it), but this selector does not work:

```
$(myUL + '>li').each( etc, etc...
```

It gives me the error "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]" on this selector in Firebug.

If I use `$('li', myUL)` it gives me ALL of the 'li's withing the ul, not just the direct children, which is not what I want. I only want the direct children.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var li_children = myUL.children('li');
```

(Properly, a `<ul>` can only have `<li>` children anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('>li', myUl)
```

That should be sufficient?

Comment: That will probably work but it should be noted that Mr. Resig (and others) deprecate the use of the context argument, preferring `.find()`.

Comment: I prefer `.find()` myself, actually because I don't need to go back if I've already typed `myUl`. People usually try to be more succinct in their answers, though and that's probably why I did it.. otherwise someone would have said "you can use a context".

Comment: I don't think you're a bad person for using it, I just point it out because it's Official Dogma :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myUL = Jquery('ul#theID');
jQuery('>li', myUL);


jQuery selector works this way
jQuery(selector, context);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not use the tag name at the start of a selector that ends with an ID. ID alone is the fastest selector. Using a direct children method will be faster than a selector. Also not adding in a selector to the .children() method will allow jQuery to skip the filtering step that shouldn't be required as you should have all 'li' children regardless:

```
var $myUls = $( "#theID" ).children();
```

Cheers,
awirick